# Updating the value of a variable in php code if submit button is clicked

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm doing a simple form where there are two text boxes and when I input the values and click the button, the entered values would be set/updated to the variables in the php code. It updates the values but for that session only and if I refresh the page, I need to input the values again.

When I click submit, it would not show any error and is internally updated but the old/default values of the variables is still there.`

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <form action="/editUser.php" method="POST">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>E-mail:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="emailChange" autocomplete="off" required></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hash Key:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="hashChange" autocomplete="off" required></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" name="submitEdit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm acceptbtn" value="Change Value">
  </form>
</div>


<?php 
//edit username and hash
$username = "aaronferrerquitoriano@gmail.com";
$hash = "4a95acef14a537bb3d32bc6aad8cb80baa9d18f9ac06b3158f50784e6735c4c6";
if(isset($_POST['submitEdit'])){
$username = $_POST['emailChange'];
$hash = $_POST['hashChange'];
}
?>
```

Comment: @HtmHell I just added it I don't know how to create another snippet. Sorry I'm new to StackOverflow.

Comment: You have to use some kind of a database to store your values. PHP variables will not be kept after a refresh. Take a look at MySQL with PHP tutorials

Comment: Quite possible that [session variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) might be sufficient for your needs here.

Comment: @HtmHell is there another way to do that without altering the database?

Comment: @GregSchmidt how do I apply these session variables in the php code though? What should I change?

Comment: First, you read the manual on how to handle session variables in PHP. Then try writing some code. Google the problems you run into. Come back here with a fresh question if you have specific problems.

Comment: @JavsP.Aqui If you need the data to be saved only for a session (until the user exist from the browser) then it will be sufficient. What are your intentions?

Answer (score 0):

In place of your php, use this code.

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['submitEdit'])){
$username = "aaronferrerquitoriano@gmail.com";
$hash = "4a95acef14a537bb3d32bc6aad8cb80baa9d18f9ac06b3158f50784e6735c4c6";
}
if(isset($_POST['submitEdit'])){
$username = $_POST['emailChange'];
$hash = $_POST['hashChange'];
}
?>
```

Hope this would help you.